# Is there a way to send message to facebook messenger-user selected by id

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am developing an app that uses facebook messenger to send links that open the app with a deeplink. 
Then i want the user receiving the link to only be able to respond to the user that the link originated from. I cant find a solution for this however.

I'm using the react-native-fbsdk and there is a prop called peopleIds in common parameters for shareContent, but i cant get it to work with sendButton.
Whenever i'm trying to send a link all my facebook contacts show.
If there is a way to directly send a reply i'm happy to hear about it!

This is the way that i have tried to wright the shareLinkContent, if someone sees an error please tell me.

```js
  state = {
    shareLinkContent: shareLinkContent = {
      contentType: 'link',
      contentUrl: 'www.somelink.com',
      commonParameters: commonParameters = {
        peopleIds: ['XXXXXXXXXXXXX']
      }
    }
  }
```

Thank you for answering!

Comment: Can you clarify for me what your intended interaction is? I dont fully understand, the user will select a friend to send a message to, but the bot delivers the message? Then what do you want to happen? I know the fb messenger platform well, but do not understand your use case, would love to help.

Comment: I'm sorry if i explained poorly. My usecase is like this: One user sends a link from my app to another friend through facebook messenger. The other person recieves the link and it opens my app with some parameters via a deeplink. Then this user makes some choises and sends a link back, but this time i want only the first sender be the only option to send to. I have the facebook id and thought that peopleIds in shareContent should do the trick but it appears not. Thanks a lot for answering, hope this was easier to understand.

Comment: Also a direct reply button would be the prefered option, if i could bypass the friends list entierly and send back to the person just by pressing a send button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand this is not possible.